# Required new man report to be displayed to run multiple collection through Newman

Tags: newman

Html report is not getting generated using newman html extra. I have created a Batch, i want the run to be captured in html file. It executes but the html report is not generated. Can you help me

Below is my code:

```
SET postman_collection=Newman.postman_collection.json
SET postman_environment=JGestab.postman_environment.json

SET postman_folder="NewManExecution"
SET postman_data="A252ST_InputSheet_Pari_V0.1.csv"
SET postman_data1="A515ST_InputSheet_Pari_V0.1.csv"

call newman run run %postman_collection% -r htmlextra,cli -e %postman_environment% -d %postman_data%  --insecure
call newman run run %postman_collection% -r htmlextra,cli -e %postman_environment% -d %postman_data1%  --insecure
```

Comment: Hi friends,Can you please reply to the above question.

Answer (score 0):

The htmlextra report is an external report to newman package and requires separate installation:

```
npm install newman-reporter-htmlextra
```

Once this is complete, re-run the batch and the report will be generated

The htmlextra report is a Postman/Newman Community Maintained Report, more details can be found here: [Newman - Using External Reporters](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#using-external-reporters)

The newman application package only get bundled with the cli, json and junit reporters as default - see here: [GitHub - postmanlabs/newman/lib/reporters/](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/tree/develop/lib/reporters)